# .htaccess - Redirect duplicated post ended in '-number/' to the same url without the -number/

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I have many duplicated post and I wanted remove them but Google already indexed them. So the idea is redirect all post with pattern [-number] in the end of the url to the same URL without number

`www.domain.com/category/post-title[-number]` to `www.domain.com/category/post-title`

Example:

```
www.domain.com/category/post-title/

www.domain.com/category/post-title-1/ -->  www.domain.com/category/post-title/

www.domain.com/category/post-title-2/ -->  www.domain.com/category/post-title/

www.domain.com/category/post-title-3/ -->  www.domain.com/category/post-title/

www.domain.com/category/post-title-4/ -->  www.domain.com/category/post-title/

www.domain.com/category/post-title-5/ -->  www.domain.com/category/post-title/

www.domain.com/category/post-title-6/ -->  www.domain.com/category/post-title/
```

I have tried some Rewrite Rules on the .htaccess but didn't work at all.

For example this one:

```
#RewriteRule ^/(.+)-[0-9]+/$  /$1 R=301
```

`(.+)`  --> it will match the letters of the 'post-title'

`-[0-9]+/`  --> It will match the '-' and the number of the tittle

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're close. Add the following to your `.htaccess` file in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags that were created by WordPress:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.+)-[0-9]+/$ /$1 [R=301]
```

Your `.htaccess` should looks like the following if it hasn't been modified by another plugin:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom Rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.+)-[0-9]+/$ /$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

As a result it will do the following:

```
http://example.com/category/post-title[-NUMBER]
```

Redirects to:

```
http://example.com/category/post-title
```

Comment: HI Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan Thanks a lot for your answer. I completely forgot about this question. In the end, I removed the duplicated post and I asked Google to reindex the site.. After few months every is OK with the SEO. If I have in the future similar problem I will try your code. Thanks again!

Comment: @andresgl Glad you solved your issue. Please click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that this question has been solved.

Comment: No longer works here, end in a server error

Answer (score 0):

you can test this in the 404 template and do a redirection

try this :

```
add_filter("404_template", function ($template) {

    var_dump($GLOBALS["wp_query"]->query);


    return $template;

}, 10, 1);
```

Comment: Hi @mmm not sure at all what you mean.. Thank you!

Comment: you can do redirection in this action instead of the .hatccess file

Comment: Could you give an example, please? I am not sure how to do it. Thanks

Comment: have you try the code of my answer ?

Comment: Yes..  any change at all www.domain.com/category/post-title-3/ still www.domain.com/category/post-title-3/ and not to www.domain.com/category/post-title Thanks